# .Net Core - Mailkit SSLHandshake error after publish to Ubuntu platform

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04, mailkit

I published my ASP .net core app for linux. I got issue with framework MailKit v12 cuz in Debug all work without problems, i connecting to mail server fetching data with imap etc but when i publish app all the time i have SSL hanshake error.

I thought it might be some server side config problem but it won't. I wrote fast console app in VSCode and run in debug on linux, and it work but my released version from app doesn't want to..

Linux: Ubutnu 18.04 LTS
.net version: net5
releasedservice config:

```
[Unit]
Description=My desc

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=my/path
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet my/path/App.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My mailkit code:
[image]

Exception photo:

[image]

I'm not sure does it's important (i think it's not) but to run service in schedule i use Hangfire Framework. I think apache config it's also doesn't much important but i'm using Http on *:80 to acceess, not ssl yet. Nevertheless if on ubuntu it run with same configuration doesnt should work also with app?

**Please advice me about what i should read more or just did you meet same issue cuz any advices from MailKit's GitHub doesnt help me.**

Comment: The error message talks about 6 different possible causes of the error. What have you checked if any of those 6 possible causes?

Comment: BTW, you posted in the image of the error message a link with information on that error that could be useful. Consider editing the question and adding the exception as text, so you and others can look at that very likely helpful github link.

Comment: What version of TLS do you want to use?  You have an old version of Ubuntu which may not support TLS 1.3.  See : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases?force_isolation=true.  what version of Net are you using?  You should use Net 4.7.2 or later and target Core 5.0.  then make sure you are using Operating System for TLS and not Net.

Comment: @Cleptus Thank you for response i will edit post.  About these 6 posibilites i found it not so much importent (maybe i shouldn't) because i don't understand different between app I published from windows (for linux x64 platform) where doesn't work that functionality and version wrote in Linux and published for linux which working. I do not believe that importent is does server is using self-signed cert or not if it is working on version wrote on linux.. quite confusing for me.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for response. It's true that isn't it newest Ubuntu version and TLS cuz I'm using 1.0 or 1.1 nevertheless  it work on windows. About .net: i think it's good idea to check it and i will. 
Target framework is .net 5.0
on ubuntu installed is 3.1 and 5.0 which are supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

Comment: It may be the kernel : https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/?force_isolation=true  I believe the TLS is done in the kernel in linux.  Older version of the kernel may not support the TLS version.  In windows TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were disabled by Microsoft Security push last June on servers.  So if you are working on Windows it probably is TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Yo ucan use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check TLS version on working Windows and then compare with you Linux machine.

Comment: FWIW, MailKit by default only supports TLS v1.2 and v1.3 for security reasons. However, the ImapClient.SslProtocols property can be set to add support for older TLS/SSL versions.

Comment: @jstedfast Thank you for response. Yes can be set to older, and i did it in code as you can check on screen. If you mean other method then i used please let me know

Comment: @jdweng i checked tls with https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check on both platforms and both are TLS1.3. Both are the same. Sooo ubuntu may not use 1.0 but force trying on 1.3 as you said.. i need to check/change it but why when i wrote console app on linux and run it then worked.. hmm..

Comment: I think rebuilding solved issue.  Not changing to Core 3.1.  TLS 1.3 will not work in Net.  The encryption mode isn't supported.   So you must be using the operating system for TLS with Core 3.1 and wasn't using operating system with Core 5.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to downgrade to .net core 3.1 as @jdweng suggested to check and this solve problems. Thank you all for help!! :)